# ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings Web.Config SQL Credentials Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am placing my SQL Connection credentials in my Web.config (Debug and Release) XML folders

```
<add name="myName"
        connectionString="Data Source = myDatabase;Initial Catalog=myTable;Integrated Security=True; User Id=TestUser Password=P@ssw0rd"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I am using the following for my C# for debugging:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;

namespace OfflineWebApps
   {
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myName"].ConnectionString;

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("****** TEST ****** " + connString + " Connection String");  //Used to return ConnectionString
        }
    }
}
```

when I run the program, I receive the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
```

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here is what I have tried to debug on my own:
- I have "using System.Configuration;"

- I am referencing System.Configuration.DLL
- The names are spelled correctly in the XML and the C# references.
- I have tried using ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myName"] but I get an empty string.
- This has been replicated on three different machines at two different sites.

Thank you.

Edit:  Added Data Source in my connectionString XML

Answer (score 0):

The `Data Source` property will need to be included in the connection string with the name of the SQL Server instance that you will connect to.

```
<add name="myName"
        connectionString="Data Source=YourSQLServerInstance;Initial Catalog=myTable;Integrated Security=True; User Id=TestUser Password=P@ssw0rd"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: My apologies.  When I added the code, I omitted that part for "security".  it is there, please see my edit above.